# With Tensorflow C, is there a modeling load example site?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Using Python, I extracted hd5, pb, and tflite model files (from mnist)
I created an app with Tensorflow Lite on Android, and I used tflite to recognize images.
Next, I want to use C to recognize images in MacOS.
But there's no example source.
Tensorflow installation is complete.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

The source below is also operating normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a good example site that even beginners can easily understand?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
http://iamsurya.com/inference-in-c-using-tensorflow/

Comment: @TalalAlrawajfeh Thanks, but it's not working. Tensorflow 2.3.1 is in use, is it not available in that version?